# Proving that every connected graph has a vertex whose removal will not disconnect the graph.

Tags: graph-theory

I have not done much proofs before this and need some guidance. I know that for a simple graph such as this :

```
node - node - node -node
```

Removing the first and last vertex will not disconnect the graph. So far, I can think of two cases: Where there are leaves, or nodes with degree of 1. Where there are no leaves, which means all nodes have degrees 2 or more.

In the first case, removing the leaf will not disconnect the graph. In the second case, removing any should not disconnect the graph. Problem is, I don't know how to formulate this into a good proof.

Comment: Your reasoning in the second case is wrong: Take two k-cliques and a single vertex. Connect the single vertex to a vertex in each k-clique. Then the single vertex has degree 2, and has the lowest degree of all vertices, but removing it would disconnect the graph.

Comment: Hint: Every connected graph is either a tree (which has a leaf) or contains a cycle.

Comment: Another way than what genisage suggests is to run DFS on the graph. You get a spanning Tree... and then?

Comment: Either graphs with exactly one vertex are counterexamples or the empty graph is a counterexample, depending on whether or not the empty graph counts as connected. $\;$

Comment: My solution, after thinking a while about it, was induction on the number of vertices of the graphs with minimum degree $2$. But I must admit that the idea with the spanning tree is much better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove a leaf of a spanning tree.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.

Comment: This just led to a a new insight. So I won't need something such as a cycle detection if I'm writing an DFS algorithm to delete a vertex such that the graph will still be connected. I can simply check if a vertex is already visited and if it is, then delete it!

Answer (score 6):

Choose two vertices $u,v$ which maximize the distance $\operatorname d(u,v)$. If $w$ is any other vertex of the graph, the shortest path from $v$ to $w$ does not go though $u$ (else $v$ and $w$ would be farther apart than $v$ and $u$), so deleting $u$ leaves a connected graph.